# JS snippets on my live project do not appear in my code residing on my production server

Tags: web-application, attacks, xss, webserver, javascript

I have a Django website project that is live (let's call it example.com). It's a forum where users can submit comments and reply to them. It has a Postgresql database, and gunicorn + nginx reverse proxy as the web server set up. I'm hosted on an Azure-powered virtual machine, with the Debian-based Ubuntu 14.04 lts as the OS. Lastly, note that the web application and the server sit on two separate virtual machine instances.

I suspect my servers might be compromised - I'm at the data-gathering stage where I'm ascertaining whether (i) indeed my servers are compromised (ii) whether my data is compromised too (iii) how did the compromise happen, so that I don't get hacked again.

In Django applications, there's a `base.html` file that all other `.html` files inherit (or `extend` in Django). This `base.html` file contains the `<head>` tag with required meta tags etcetra, so one doesn't have to replicate it in every template file.

My `base.html` file has some javascript code in it that *I did not write*. In fact, I don't use javascript in my code at all. This malicious javascript snippet redirects my users to adverts (it's a money making hack). If I log into my web application's production server and `nano` to the `base.html` file (i.e. open it in a text editor), the offending snippets of javascript *do not appear there*.

Secondly, when I inspect element on my live website (browser: Firefox), I see an `ev` button next to the collapsed  tag of my website:

[image]

This is apparently an events button to debug JS in Mozilla's code inspector. If I press it, I see:

[image]

I'm unsure what's `:37` (port 37?). Moreover, if I press the pause (debug) button in front of `click`, I am taken to one of the JS snippets residing in my `base.html` code:

[image]

My confusion is regarding how can these JS snippets be part of my live website when the files in my production server appear to be *without* them?

I'm guessing finding the source of the hack would require going deeper into this. I haven't installed SSL yet, but I suspect my problem can't be helped by that. This is a two-person project - and the other person is a non-techie, cultural anthropology major specializing in South Asian studies, so I'm sure she has nothing to do with it.

---

I have set `rules.v4` for `iptables` to:

```
*filter
# Allow all outgoing, but drop incoming and forwarding packets by default
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# Custom per-protocol chains
:UDP - [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:ICMP - [0:0]

# Acceptable UDP traffic

# Acceptable TCP traffic
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Acceptable ICMP traffic

# Boilerplate acceptance policy
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop invalid packets
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Pass traffic to protocol-specific chains
## Only allow new connections (established and related should already be handled)
## For TCP, additionally only allow new SYN packets since that is the only valid
## method for establishing a new TCP connection
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ICMP

# Reject anything that's fallen through to this point
## Try to be protocol-specific w/ rejection message
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# Commit the changes
COMMIT

*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
1COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

Comment: And the adverts are not placed there by the hosting company?

Comment: It depends how the attack, if an attack, is being performed, this could be django I have never used it so cannot be sure. though it is waiting for you to press a key? by the looks of it... if this is an attack then SSL could stop it depending on the type of attack.... though as said previously this could be ads. I would need to see your site. The way SSL would stop an attack like that is by not allowing interception and modification. though its starting to look more and more like ads

Comment: Are there any `<script` tags at all in your header file?

Comment: @schroeder: yes, the hosting company never placed ads there. @That1Guy: I never put any script tags, but I see a ton of them in my header file now. A few are legit (`new relic`, `google analytics`), but most are some kind of ad-related script tags *that I never put*. @silverpenguin: Yes, I'm just trying to get as much information right now as possible. It was flagged in my previous ques that my servers might be compromised. So I'm now quite confused about why my files on the production server aren't defaced, but those being served are. Your SSL theory does make sense to me.

Comment: Do you see those snippets when looking at the originally-sent html source?  That is, what's sent by the server, before javascript has had a chance to muck with the dom?  I think Firefox's view source will show that, but `curl` certainly will.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov: Okay, this situation is in flux. Right now, the offending JS snippets *are gone* (tried both curl and Mozilla inspector). I do have JS snippets from Goog Analytics and New Relic, but those I authorized. The snippets related to ads *are gone*. The only change I made over the day is settomg a basic firewall on my server (I put the `iptables` config in the question too if you want to read it). I still haven't gotten around to installing SSL. What's going on?

Comment: Can you recursively `grep` for parts of the malicious JS on your entire Django project directory? The parts that handle HTTP in Django could've been altered to add the malicious code even though it's not present in the template files.

Comment: This post is pretty old, not sure why it was in the sidebar of SE... but for anyone that stumbles on it - this could simply be a browser extension injecting them.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have pulled out of their page is New Relic Browser monitoring. This is Javascript which lets the website track the performance of pages for their live sites and for the customers using it.

It provides performance data back for how long the page took to load, where in the world you are from and time each element loading to show where any degraded performance may be.

You can find out more information about this product at 
http://newrelic.com/browser-monitoring

Comment: Google Analytics and New Relic snippets are indeed there. But also snippets referring to adperformancenetwork, visadd, etc.